# Realtek optical out

Tags: audio

I recently tried a PCI sound card and wasn't satisfied with it. So, now I tried to switch back to my integrated HDA sound card. Everything else is fine, but I get no sound from optical out. The light is there and coxial is fine too, but no sound is played. I'd say I've forgotten something, but after three hours I still can't figure out what. The setup used to work before I tried the other card.

Checklist:
- Receiver set to OPT1
- Receiver toslink jack works with my TV
- Red light is there
- BIOS is set to SPDIF
- Sound card is set to "Digital Output(RCA+optical)"

Specs:
Win7 x64
Realtek R2.55 drivers
Onkyo TX-SR606 receiver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved, faulty cable. Altho there was the red light, it wasn't intense enough.

Comment: Please mark this answer as accepted by clicking the check mark on the left. =)